# How to create a task with as trigger a successful task in Qlik Sense

Tags: api-design, qliksense

hi i'm trying to create a task with a trigger that start on successful task, the task and the trigger seem to be correct but when the father task end doesn't start the trigger of the new one, i follow the script that i found in the documentation at https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/April2020/Subsystems/RepositoryServiceAPI/Content/Sense_RepositoryServiceAPI/RepositoryServiceAPI-Reload-Task-Create.htm This is my code:

```
{
    "task":{
        "app": {
                "id": "d7f0f4f2-1705-4ac2-9043-fc5e2710e634"
        },
        "name": "Reload test",
        "isManuallyTriggered": false,
        "taskType": 0,
        "enabled": true,
        "taskSessionTimeout": 1440,
        "maxRetries": 0,
        "schemaPath": "ReloadTask"
    },
    "compositeEvents": [ {
        "timeConstraint": {
            "days": 0,
            "hours": 0,
            "minutes": 360,
            "seconds": 0
        },
        "compositeRules": [
        {
            "reloadTask": {
                "id": "e878a7f1-18ef-47fe-aab7-f02ae3bf585b"
            },
        "ruleState": 1
        }
        ],
        "name":"EventTrigger",
        "eventType": 1,
        "enabled": true
    }]
}
```

any idea of what is the problem? from postman i receive 201 and in Qlik seem everything ok but it's not working. Thanks

Comment: I am not seeing this be an issue see [here](https://i.imgur.com/ihiYuO6.png) for an example.

What are you seeing? Is `Reload test` created? Does `Reload test` have a trigger which is an event trigger? Does the same process work when done using the Management Console?

Comment: hi, Reload Test is created and the trigger is an event trigger but if i start the father task at the end of that doesn't start Reload Test so seems that the trigger doesn't work. In the qmc is equal to another one that i created from the qmc but the one created from qmc work in the right way, the other one created from api no. Can i ask you what version of Qlik are you using?

Comment: Thanks it was a release version of Qlik Sense issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it was a release version of Qlik Sense issue